# SP13 - Exclude File Title From Search Results

Tags: 2013, document-library, search, search-results

Scenario: I created a Advance Search Web Pat with Result Source connected to a particular document library.  When I enter a topic the results returns document title and more metadata.

Question:  Is there a way to exclude the document title from the search results but have the other results appear?

I have changed the search setting to no but I want the search results to still appear but without the document title.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- Navigate to the site settings page by clicking settings gear 
- On the Site Settings page, click on "Searchable Columns" link under search group.
```

[image]

```
- Select the check box next to the column(s) that you want to suppress from search and click Ok.![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwWti.png)
```